# Replace a text keyword with a "Page Break" element in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to replace a specific text keyword with a page break. Here's what I've tried:

```
body.findText("%PAGE_BREAK%").getElement().appendPageBreak()
```

and

```
body.replaceText("%PAGE_BREAK%", "").asBody().appendPageBreak()
```

I'm trying to edit existing documents which have `%page_break%` somewhere and replace it with an actual page break element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will suffice under the assumption that "%page_break%" appears either at the end of a paragraph, or in a paragraph of its own. The script searches the text for this pattern, and appends a PageBreak element to the end of the element (paragraph) containing the found text. Then it removes the pattern.

```
function pageBreaks() {
  var searchPattern = "%page_break%";
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = body.findText(searchPattern); 
  while (found) {
    found.getElement().getParent().appendPageBreak();
    found = body.findText(searchPattern, found);
  }
  body.replaceText(searchPattern, "");
}
```

It does not make much sense to place page breaks inside of paragraphs, but Google Docs supports this, and there is [`Paragraph.insertPageBreak`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertpagebreakchildindex) method for that. However, to use it you would need to first split the Text element containing the search pattern so that a page break can go in between two Texts. (A Text element cannot contain any other elements.)