# Add page break before text in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to insert a page break before certain text.

I tried the solution in this post: [Replace a text keyword with a "Page Break" element in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421966/replace-a-text-keyword-with-a-page-break-element-in-apps-script)

Which adds the page break after the text, played around with the code and couldn't get it to add it before. As a workaround I was trying to append a paragraph text after I append the page Break, but couldn't get it work.

Comment: When you say `before text`, do you mean splitting the paragraph the text is in and splitting this section of the paragraph to the next page, or adding the page break before the paragraph in which your text is?

Comment: I have a text called Chapter X, I want the page break to be added before that text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to insert the pagebreak before a text word in Google Document using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose the following sample script using Google Docs API. At Google Docs API, the page can be inserted to the middle of text using `index`. So I thought that this direction might be a bit simple and the process cost might be able to be also reduced. The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve all contents from Google Document using the method of "documents.get" in Docs API.
2. Create the request body for using the method of "documents.batchUpdate" in Docs API.
3. Request the request body to the method of "documents.batchUpdate" in Docs API.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document, and please set `searchPattern`. And, please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services.

```
function myFunction() {
  const searchText = "{{page break}}";  // Please set text. This script inserts the pagebreak before this text.
  
  // 1. Retrieve all contents from Google Document using the method of "documents.get" in Docs API.
  const docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const res = Docs.Documents.get(docId);
  
  // 2. Create the request body for using the method of "documents.batchUpdate" in Docs API.
  let offset = 0;
  const requests = res.body.content.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e.paragraph) {
      e.paragraph.elements.forEach(f => {
        if (f.textRun) {
          const re = new RegExp(searchText, "g");
          let p = null;
          while (p = re.exec(f.textRun.content)) {
            ar.push({insertPageBreak: {location: {index: p.index + offset}}});
          }
        }
      })
    }
    offset = e.endIndex;
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  
  // 3. Request the request body to the method of "documents.batchUpdate" in Docs API.
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, docId);
}
```

- In this sample script, `const searchPattern = "{{page break}}"` is used as the text for inserting the pagebreak. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [InsertPageBreakRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertpagebreakrequest)

### Added:

I confirmed that `google-docs-api` is also included in your tags of your question. So I proposed a sample script for using Google Docs API. But from your following replying, it seems that you wanted to use Google Docs API without enabling Google Docs API at Advanced Google services. I couldn't notice about this from your question and tags.

> is there a way of doing this without having to enable the Google Docs API in the Apps Script environment? I get a Reference Error for Docs.Documents.get(docId) if I don't.

About your replying, I add one more sample script. In this sample script, Google Docs API is used with UrlFetchApp. So Google Docs API of Advanced Google services is not used. But, in this case, Google Docs API is required to be enabled at API console. So I propose 2 patterns for this.

1. Please link GCP to GAS project and enable Google Docs API at API console.
2. Please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services once and save the GAS project. Here, please wait for minutes. And then, please disable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services. In the current stage, it seems that even when Google Docs API is disabled at Advanced Google services, Google Docs API is not disabled at API console. But I'm not sure whether this is the permanent situation. But, now, I thought that this might be able to be used for this your situation.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please enable Google Docs API at API console by doing one of them as I proposed above and run the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  const searchText = "{{page break}}";  // Please set text. This script inserts the pagebreak before this text.
  
  // 1. Retrieve all contents from Google Document using the method of "documents.get" in Docs API.
  const accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const url1 = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/" + docId;
  const response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken}});
  const res = JSON.parse(response1.getContentText());

  // 2. Create the request body for using the method of "documents.batchUpdate" in Docs API.
  let offset = 0;
  const requests = res.body.content.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e.paragraph) {
      e.paragraph.elements.forEach(f => {
        if (f.textRun) {
          const re = new RegExp(searchText, "g");
          let p = null;
          while (p = re.exec(f.textRun.content)) {
            ar.push({insertPageBreak: {location: {index: p.index + offset}}});
          }
        }
      })
    }
    offset = e.endIndex;
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  
  // 3. Request the request body to the method of "documents.batchUpdate" in Docs API.
  const url2 = `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${docId}:batchUpdate`;
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {method: "post", payload: JSON.stringify({requests: requests}), contentType: "application/json", headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken}});

  // DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); // This is used for automatically adding a scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents by the script editor.
}
```

#### Note:

- When an error related to Google Docs API occurs, please enable Google Docs API at API console again.

Comment: This answer is brilliant. Thank you! Btw, is there a way of doing this without having to enable the Google Docs API in the Apps Script environment? I get a Reference Error for Docs.Documents.get(docId) if I dont.

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. In my proposed answer, Google Docs API of Advanced Google services is used. So in this case, Google Docs API is required to be enabled at Advanced Google services. I think that there is no method for using Google Docs API of Advanced Google services without enabling Google Docs API at Advanced Google services. When Google Docs API is not enabled at Advanced Google services, such error occurs. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Diego For example, after Google Docs API was enabled at Advanced Google services, even when Google Docs API is disabled at Advanced Google services, it seems that Google Docs API is not enabled at API console. But I'm not sure whether this is the permanent situation. When this situation is permanent, I think that you can use Docs API with UrlFetchApp without enabling Docs API. Or, by linking GCP to GAS project, you can also use Docs API by UrlFetchApp by enabling Docs API at API console. But I'm not sure whether this is the same direction you expect, I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No need to apologize, I really appreciate your response. When you using UrlFetchApp, does that mean calling the API endpoint: "https://docs.googleapis.com" throught it? Would it be simple to call its methods then?

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. I think that it's yes.

Comment: @Diego Now, I added one more sample script for achieving your replying. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks! That works exactly right. I would give you more upvotes if I could. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying and this current situation. I apologize for this. Because if my answer didn't resolve your issue, I have to apologize and think of other solution. Can I ask you about it?