# Can I use Google Apps Script to intelligently add page/column breaks based on how much space appended text will take up in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, page-break

I wrote a custom script that takes Google Sheet data and formats it to generate a Google Doc. The sheet data updates automatically and I have to periodically generate a new report for client use. (Overall this relatively seamless -- it has saved me a huge amount of time!)

Unfortunately, I always have to manually format the report afterward, adding column breaks to make sure individual records appear continuously without wrapping to the next column or page. Is there a way to have the script do this for me? So far as I've found, Apps Script doesn't have a way to "figure out" where on the page the cursor is or determine how much room is left before the bottom of the page.

Comment: As far as I know, that would the issue. But what you can do alternatively is to place a certain string in your sheet. and that string will determine where you would insert a break. Similar idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65913484/14606045). If you would like to have the solution above, kindly provide a sample data and an expected output. Then I'll try to provide a similar solution.

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't include that as built-in / ready to use feature but you might build an algorithm or us IA to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As per Rubén's confirmation in the comments, there is no built-in feature to do what you want. But alternatively, there is a way to do what you want.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913377/insert-line-breaks-before-text-in-google-apps-script/65913484#65913484) shows that similar idea. You can have certain string/keywords that are placed within your source that can define where you would insert your break.

I'm not entirely sure how your data looks and it is hard to provide an exact answer. But if there is a pattern to your data in sheets and you can preemptively define where you can insert your column break, then that can be doable.

Basically, you will need to design how your data is being read (or even modify it) and format it into the document.

If you can provide a sample data and an expected output, then maybe users here can provide you a specific answer that will cater to your exact needs.